# How to convert excel dates in R

Tags: r

I have imported xlsx sheet into R `clean_employer` with below 4 variables. The date shown in R is excel date format which I need to convert to readable format.
So far I've tried below.
`clean_employer$Date <- as.Date(clean_employer$Date, origin = "1899-12-30")`With this I'm getting below error message `Error in charToDate(x) :  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`. Can you let me know how to resolve this. Thx!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you save it as char. You have to convert it to numeric first before using `as.Date`. Please add `as.numeric` before convert to date. You can check the [R documentation here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/as.Date). Here is the sample code:

```
# Example data
clean_employer <- data.frame(
  Date = c("43834", "43835", "43836") 
)

# Convert Excel date to Date format
clean_employer$Date <- as.Date(as.numeric(clean_employer$Date), origin = "1899-12-30") 

# Print the result
print(clean_employer)
```

Sample output:

[image]

Here is the [sample source code](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/1doCiZsuuo6)